# trouble installing less with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, less

So I just installed node and npm. My cmdprompt recognizes both when i test `node -v` and `npm -v`. However, i cannot install anything (less or bower) using npm.

`npm -install -g less` yields:

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g less
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;npm\npm\lessc -> C:\Users\user\AppData
\Roaming\npm;npm\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc
less@2.5.1 C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;npm\npm\node_modules\less
├── graceful-fs@3.0.8
├── mime@1.3.4
├── image-size@0.3.5
├── errno@0.1.4 (prr@0.0.0)
├── promise@6.1.0 (asap@1.0.0)
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── source-map@0.4.4 (amdefine@1.0.0)
└── request@2.60.0 (aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.1,     stringstream@0.0.4, ca
seless@0.11.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, oauth-sign@0.8.0, isstream@0.1.2, json-string
ify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@4.0.0, combined-stream@1.0.5,
mime-types@2.1.4, form-data@1.0.0-rc3, tough-cookie@2.0.0, http-signature@0.11.0
, bl@1.0.0, hawk@3.1.0, har-validator@1.8.0)
```

I've looked around stackover flow and tried changing system environment variables, but nothing seems to help. Any suggestions?

System Variables(Windows 7 Professional):

`Path`: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

`NODE_PATH`: `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

**UPDATE:**

I got it to work using:
node C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc styles.less > styles.css

but is there a way (possibly editing paths), so I do not have to enter all that and instead just `lessc styles.less > styles.css`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are using `command prompt` in non-administrator mode.
Open `command prompt` as `Admin` and try again.

It should work.

I hope you know how run `cmd` as admin.
Otherwise this might help [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this did not help. Should I change a system path in addition to running cmd prompt as an admin?